# Multiple :selectors on one CSS element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am stylizing a CSS element, and I was wondering if I could use multiple `:selectors` on one CSS element.

For instance:

```
p:hover:after {
    content: "Hello!";
}
```

Because, when I want the `p` to be hovered over, I want the `:after` selector to also be called.

Comment: Why don't you try it? http://jsfiddle.net is your friend. And yes, you can.

Comment: be as crazy as you want. `p:not(.DancingPuppets):last-of-type:hover:after`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific example is completely valid, it works as [**demonstrated here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Kn8Dm/).

As of now, the main limitation(s) pertaining to pseudo elements, is that:

> **CSS3 Selectors - 7. Pseudo-elements** [**(reference)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)
>
> **Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector**, and if present it must appear **after the sequence of simple selectors** that represents the subjects of the selector. *Note: A future version of this specification may allow multiple pseudo-elements per selector*.

Thus, neither of the following selectors would work: `p:hover:after:after`, `p:after:hover`

There is no limit on the number of simple selectors that can be chained together within the selector. And as [@BoltClock states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966260/multiple-selectors-on-one-css-element/19966293?noredirect=1#comment29725817_19966293) in the comments, there can only be one type selector or universal selector.

> **CSS3 Selectors - 4. Selector syntax** [**(reference)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax)
>
> A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator. It **always begins with a type selector or a universal selector**.

Here is a relevantly long selector that works: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/F9UT7/)

```
#parent:first-of-type:first-child > .child:last-child p:not(#element):not(#otherelement):hover:after
```

Comment: There is no limit to how many simple selectors you can chain together and in what order in a single compound selector, *except* there may only be at most one type selector *or* universal selector, and it must come first (if you don't include either, the universal selector is implied) - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selector-syntax

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks - I'll be updating the answer once I have all that figured out. But to be clear, there may be only one type/universal selector within the ***simple*** selector, right? As far as I can tell, there can be **[multiple universal](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/8g49S/)** selectors within the entire selector chain. There obviously just can't be multiples within the *simple* selector, is that right..? I can't find any references in the documentation stating this directly.

Comment: A simple selector is any one of those components that you chain together. What you have there are, well, selectors (there isn't really a full name for those yet) but each `*` is a simple selector. The selector-syntax that I linked to has all the terminology (but even then CSS2.1 and 3 have very poor terminology - Selectors 4 has much better definitions).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple [dynamic pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) are permissible.

> An example of combining dynamic pseudo-classes:
>
> ```
> a:focus { background: yellow } 
> a:focus:hover { background: white }
> ```
>
> The last selector matches A elements that are in pseudo-class :focus
>   and in pseudo-class :hover.

**Illustration:** http://jsfiddle.net/BhKuf/ *(remember to hover)*